# ng-infinite-scroll with ng-show and sticky states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, infinite-scroll, ng-show, nginfinitescroll

I am new to angular. In my single page web app, I have two tabs with ng-infinite-scroll in each of them. The two tabs are traversed between using a nav-bar,

```
    <div ng-show="$state.includes('base.videolist')||$state.includes('base.movielist')  ">
<ul class="nav navbar-fixed-top roboto nav-tabs">
   <li ui-sref="base.videolist" ui-sref-active="active"><a>Videos</a></li>
   <li ui-sref="base.movielist" ui-sref-active="active"><a>Movies</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and each tab resides in two ui-views as shown below.

```
<div id="bvl" ui-view="videolist" ng-show="$state.includes('base.videolist')"></div>
<div id="bml" ui-view="movielist" ng-show="$state.includes('base.movielist')"></div>
```

When using ng-show, the height of the hidden div is set to 0 by angular. thereby triggering the infinite-scroll infintely.

I dont want to use ng-if because i want to maintain the scroll state of the lists.

How to handle this?

PS. i use sticky states for both the lists to maintain states between master detail view of the list elements.

Comment: Use `ng-class` perhaps?

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: @Ladmerc I don't know how to get both the scrollers to work.

Comment: The documentation here https://github.com/sroze/ngInfiniteScroll
says that you should define `<div infinite-scroll="$ctrl.myPagingFunction()" infinite-scroll-distance="3"></div>`; that's assuming you have defined `myPagingFunction` in the controller

Comment: @Ladmerc the functions are triggered properly. The issue is with the timing of the trigger. The trigger is fired multiple times because the height of one div is set to 0 because of ng-show

Comment: Do you have a fiddle to replicate the issue?

Comment: @Aruna i am not sure how to create a fiddle as the page tries to pull data from my local database.

Comment: You can hard code the data by commenting out the api part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/documentation.html

> infinite-scroll-disabled (optional) - {boolean} - A boolean expression that, when true, indicates that the infininite scroll expression should not be evaluated even if all other conditions are met.

If you want to use ng-show="showIt" to hide an element containing an infinite scroll, you can add infinite-scroll-disabled="!showIt" to stop it from trying to load more items while hidden.

Here is a [jsbin example](https://jsbin.com/megewog/1/edit?html,js,console,output) with 2 infinite scrolling divs that can each be hidden with ng-show without the hidden infinite scroll trying to load more items every time you scroll.

Comment: how to maintain the scroll states of each of the divs when switching between them?